# How to zip files using last modified date and time using shell command in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to zip files using last modified date and time with following shell command in linux.

```
zip -rt $(date +"%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S") destination.zip source_documents
```

E.g

```
zip -rt 2015-03-24:17:14:39 destination.zip source_documents
```

It does not works. it takes whole day files.

Comment: Actually your question is answer for me. I need to copy whole day files and it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Following the man page you need to use the time format `mmddyyyy`. The command should look like this:

```
zip -rt $(date +"%m%d%Y") destination.zip source_documents
```

which gives (today):

```
zip -rt 03242015 destination.zip source_documents
```

Comment: I want to zip files using date and time.

Answer (score 0):

Since `zip -t` doesn't take the time of day into consideration, let's `find` do the job, e. g.

```
find source_documents -newermt "2015-03-24 17:14:38" | zip -@ destination
```